# What's difference between `variable.name` and `variable.op.name`?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose `x` is a `Variable`, I saw use of `op.name` like `tf.scalar_summary(x.op.name, x)` in the tutorial. I am wondering if I can replace `x.op.name` with `x.name` in general.

What's the difference between the two? Are they interchangeable?

```
with tf.name_scope('ab'):
    a = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1), name="v1")

a.name
u'ab_1/v1:0'

a.op.name
u'ab_1/v1'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right now the [`Variable.name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable.name) property maps to the name of the mutable [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) in which that variable is stored (principally because a `Variable` can be used wherever a `Tensor` is expected). Tensor names are generated from the name of the operation that produces them (a `Variable` op in this case) and the index of the output to which that tensor corresponds.

You can feel free to use `tf.scalar_summary(x.name, x)` in place of `tf.scalar_summary(x.op.name, x)`, but the resulting visualizations will contain a redundant `":<N>"` in the tags.

Comment: What's `op.name` then? Or, what is `op` property?

Comment: The `op` property of a `Tensor` or a `Variable` is a pointer to the node in the TensorFlow graph that produces that tensor, or&mdash;in the case of a `Variable`&mdash;owns the storage for that tensor and produces a mutable reference to that storage. Ops have simpler names in general because TensorFlow graphs are represented as sets of named ops, and each tensor is named implicitly based on the op that produces it.

Comment: So if I do `tf.assign(some_variable.op.outputs[0], some_data)`, I'll assign to `some_variable`? If not, how can I create an assignment operation that assigns to a `tf.Variable` if I only have its `op` property?